# Как изменить стандартное контекстное меню?

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

В новом проекте имеются несколько стандартных меню.

- при клике ПКМ по верхней панели окна;
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
- в TextEdit.
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каким образом можно изменить данные меню и MS Visual 2010?
т.е. удалить некоторые пункты?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/wdee4yb6%28v=vs.140%29.aspx по данной ссылке изменение меню самого Visual, т.е. не подходит

Comment: `C++/CLI` - ни рыба, ни мясо. Вы не найдёте ни примеров кода на нём, ни внятной документации. Насчёт системного меню. Разбираетесь в нативном C++ - начните [отсюда](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468864(v=vs.85).aspx). Больше понимаете .NET, смотрите [сюда](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/CSCustomizeSysMenu-024ccb7f). По поводу второго меню: создайте своё собственное контекстное меню и назначьте его текстбоксу.